# Asio: how to get async data back into synchronous method

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm using asio for async io, but there are some times where I'd like to "escape" the async world and get my data back into the regular synchronous world.

For instance, consider that I have a `std::deque<string> _data` that is being used in my async process (in a single thread always running in the background), and were I've created async function to read / write from it.

What is the "natural" way to read from this deque in a synchronous way from another thread ?
So far I've used atomics to do this but this feels a bit "wrong".
For example:

```
std::string getDataSync()
{
std::atomic<int> signal = 0;
std::string str;

asio::post(io_context, [this, &signal, &str] { 
str = _data.front();
_data.pop_front();
signal = 1;
});

while(signal == 0) { }
return str;

}
```

1. Is it ok to do this?
2. Does asio provide anything cleaner to do this kind of operations?

Thanks

Comment: By synchronous do you mean blocking?

Comment: @JohnFilleau yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to synchronize two threads, then you have to use sychronize primitives (like `std::atomic`). Asio doesn't provide more advanced primitives, but the STL (and boost) is full of it. For your simple example, you might want to use `std::future` and `std::promise` to move the top item of the deque to another thread.

Here is a small example. I assume that you don't want to access the deque directly from the other thread, just the top item. I also assume that you are running `boost::asio::run` in another thread.

```cpp
inline constexpr std::string pop_from_queue() { return "hello world"; }

int main() {
  auto context = boost::asio::io_context{};

  auto promise = std::promise<std::string>{};
  auto result = promise.get_future();
  boost::asio::post(context,
                    [&promise] { promise.set_value(pop_from_queue()); });

  auto thread = std::thread{[&context] { context.run(); }};
  std::cout << result.get(); // blocking
  thread.join();
}
```